# Where/how do I set the timeout for MemoryCache?

Tags: c#, .net-core, memorycache

I am setting up my MemoryCache as follows:

```
DataCache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions
{
    ExpirationScanFrequency = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
});
CacheOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
{
    AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
};
```

And then using it as follows:

```
DataCache.Set(Keys.Users, listAllUsers, CacheOptions);
```

Is this correct? It seems weird to me that I have to set it in 2 places.

Comment: Don't forget you can also set the expiration _per item_ when you add the entry into the cache.

Comment: The first one is not the cache expiration. Timeout is set in a key based fashion. The first one is for configuring the job that checks the cache for the expired keys. You should not give it a that large value. Not being so sure but the key eill expire also when it is accessed after the timeout value paased

Comment: [The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.memorycacheoptions.expirationscanfrequency?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) are pretty clear on what the scan frequency is : _"Gets or sets the minimum length of time between successive scans for expired items."_ I'd encourage trying a custom implementation of such a cache, then it becomes clear. You need a passive expiration, by which a cache line won't be considered a hit. And then you need an active method to purge expired lines from the cache. The latter is what the scan frequency is for.

Comment: @Fildor If I understand you correctly (and re-reading the documentation which in my opinion is not clear), the `MemoryCache.ExpirationScanFrequency` is how often it scans the cache for expired items. And so that should probably be between 10 & 60 seconds??? And `CacheOptions.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow` is how long until a cache value I just set will expire and be removed??? So that is good at 5 minutes (for my use case).

Comment: Expiration and removal don't happen at the same time. An expired cache line is "invisible" so to speak and will be removed during the next scan.

Comment: @Fildor I assume there's latency. But if I set a 5 minute expiration and a 15 second scan, then worst case is in 5:15 it goes away. Which is fine. By definition the expiration of items in a cache due to timeout is a range. This is all built on estimates of what the trade-offs are between being 100% up to date vs. not hitting the DB 100 times/second.

Comment: Ah, yes you're right. Just checked and the invisibility thing is a feature we added onto it because we needed the cache line to expire "sharply". So, yes: A combination of 5 mins and 15 sec cycle will give you a window of 5:00 to 5:15 of the cache line to vanish.

Comment: @Fildor If you write all your comments as an answer, happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts to expiration (by time) of a cache line:

1. The timespan after which the cache line "expires". In this case that means it becomes eligible for removal (aka "eviction"). This is a passive thing - there is no piece of code that actively sets the cache line from valid to expired, it is just a timestamp becoming "older" than "now".
2. The cycle time at which an active process is executed, that scans the cache for expired cache lines and removes them.

The combination of both result in the actual expiration and removal timespan of an individual cache line. If we take an example of expiration at 5 minutes from insertion time and a scan cycle every 15 seconds, then in best (or short) case, the cycle runs exactly so the expiration happens at the same time and the line is removed immediately after the 5 mins. The worst (or longest) case would be that the scan cycle finishes right before expiration and the cache line lives on to 5 minutes and 15 seconds (everything +/- system timing / clock inaccuracies).

If you set both to 5 minutes, you will end up with single cache lines living any time between 5 minutes and 10 minutes. (Statistically speaking, assuming insertions are normal distributed.)

For future readers of this answer: Mind this [important notice in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/caching)

> **There are two MemoryCache classes within .NET**, one in the System.Runtime.Caching namespace and the other in the Microsoft.Extensions.Caching namespace

(emphasis by me)

Also mind, that there is also a SlidingExpiration, which is **not** addressed in the question and neither in this answer. The SlidingExpiration will extend the expiration threshold when the cache line is hit. Recommendation if using it is to set both sliding and absolute, to avoid that a frequently hit cache line *never* actually gets evicted (which *can* cause problems).

Comment: And we're supposed to use `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching` - correct?

Comment: @DavidThielen If I remeber correctly, the link in the answer should contain a section where they speak about which one to use where and why. UPDATE: Nope, it was here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-7.0#systemruntimecachingmemorycache